# Load while push to another viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, load, pushviewcontroller

When i push to my detail viewcontroller after clicking the collectionview cell it take time to load detailview Controller.
**MainViewController.m**

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    DetailViewController *objDetailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewController"];
    objDetailViewController.objProduct = [arrList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDetailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**DetailViewConteroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setInitialValues];
    [self productDetailAPI];//WS CALL

}
```

Comment: The operations or function calling viewDidLoad in  DetailViewConteroller.m put into nsoperation or @selector

Answer (score 3):

Is the API call running on the main thread?
You should make network calls on the background thread to not block the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

if "productDetilAPI" is a web request function, it will stop the UI, as mentioned in the above answer, so what you should do is

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(productDetailAPI)
                           withObject:nil];
```

Hope this help